# Overpass API: Recurse up and filter

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to find all ways containing a specific node. I do so with:

```
    [out:json];
    (
        node(<NODE-ID>);
        <;
        
    );
    out body;
```

Now is there a way to filter the result I got using the recurse up?

I would like to receive only ways and and only such which are available for cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using a workaround. I took all ways close to the node coordinate and then recursed down, to also receive the nodes.

```
(
    way[maxspeed](around:1,<lat>,<lon>);
    >;
);
out geom;
```

Comment: This query is not very efficient, use  node( 1234); way(bn)[maxspeed]; instead. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Recurse_.28n.2C_w.2C_r.2C_bn.2C_bw.2C_br.29 for details.

Comment: Nice thank you, I was looking for something to reference the found nodes.